# Access variable from another non MonoBehaviour class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I would like to get a variable from another class in Unity

```
public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject lookTarget;
    public GameObject MainCamera;

    public GameObject nextMovePoint;

    private int currentPoint = 0;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Paths
    {
        public float time;
        public Transform[] movePoints;


    }
    public Paths[] Path;




    void Update()
    {
        Paths paths = gameObject.GetComponent<Paths>();
        Debug.Log (paths.movePoints [currentPoint]);



        if (nextMovePoint.transform.position != paths.movePoints [currentPoint].position)
        {
            currentPoint += 1;
            nextMovePoint.transform.position = paths.movePoints [currentPoint].position;
        }
        iTween.MoveTo(nextMovePoint,iTween.Hash("time",paths.time));
    }
```

I want to get the movePoints from class Paths, but GetComponent gives me an error? How do I get that variable?

Still struggling with this, anyone got an idea?

Comment: Does the gameObject that has `CameraMove` attached on it also have `Paths` on it? GetComponent gets the component (in this case, a script) from the selected gameObject. If it's from another gameObject you need to locate that gameobject first then do GetComponent from that one and look at the variable. `GameObject.Find("Object with paths").GetComponent<Paths>();`. You shouldn't do this in the `Update()` method however, since that runs every frame and this is something you only need to do one time, right? Do it in the `Start()` method and save the `Paths` variable as a class variable to be used.

Comment: Paths is not attachted. How would I do it? It isn't in the inspector, it's in another script which is attachted to the object.

Comment: Then GetComponent on the other script and then get it through there, if that script has it as a variable. `Paths paths = GetComponent<AnotherScript>().pathsVariable;` if `AnotherScript` is on another gameobject, you must first get that gameobject.

Comment: You can't do 'Paths paths =' from another script. Also I don't have another script I just want ''movePoints'' from the class called 'Paths' in the class called 'CameraMove', in 1 script.

Comment: Instead of writing C# everywhere in your question, you should just put C# in the tag section like you did for unity3d.  I realized that this question is something different so I re-opened it and changed the title to match what you are doing. Are you still struggling with this?

Comment: So both the script containing this CameraMove class and the script containing Paths class are attached to the same GameObject, right? Also, can you show us the error message and the stacktrace of your error?

Comment: You class `Paths` isn't even a `MonoBehaviour` class as your question title suggests. It's missing the `: MonoBehaviour` part like the `CameraMove` class has. And if you want to access variables from that class, just do as @maximelian1986 explained in [his answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933135/access-variable-from-another-monobehaviour-class/42945552#42945552), it's the right answer.

Comment: @Programmer, Sorry. I am used to another forum. I put C# in the code because I could only choose html code. So I wanted to make clear it was C#.

Comment: @PJvG I can't make it a MonoBehaviour class, because then it doesn't do what I want it to do in the inspector. It will change.

Comment: Still got the issue, so if anyone has an idea please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *do not* need to use `GetComponent` to get access to your paths.

First, I'm going to clean up your naming a little bit so that what we're talking about a little clearer:

```
public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject LookTarget;
    public GameObject MainCamera;
    public GameObject NextMovePoint;
    public Path[] Paths;

    private int _currentPoint = 0;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Path {
    public float Time;
    public Transform[] MovePoints;
}
```

As I understand it, you want to use your `Paths` in your `Update` event. Because `Paths` is just a regular variable on the component, like `LookTarget` or `MainCamera`, you can just refer to it directly. Thus:

```
void Update() {
    Path path = Paths[/*some index*/];
    Debug.Log(path.MovePoints[_currentPoint]);
    // etc.
}
```

`GetComponent` is used to grab a different `MonoBehaviour` which is attached to the game object. When it's part of the serialized information, it's already on your class and you can just use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

From you code I see that your Path class is inner(local class) of your CameraMove class. So I think you want to move it to separate class(read like file) and attach that as component to what ever game object you need. So then you can use `getComponent<Path>()` on that object. However if you want Path class to be inner class so you need to initiate (in Start())it like

```
Path[0]=new Path(); //etc
```

Then you can use it inside your CameraMove class as

```
Path[0].movePoints[currentPoint];
```

But if you explain more what you want to achieve then I can provide more accurate solution.

Comment: ''and attach that as component to what ever game object you need.'' How would I do that? It's not a monobehaviour.

Comment: Ok, so you can make it MonoBehaviour. I don't see any reason why it is cant be so. Or you can use it as 'However if you want Path class to be inner class so you need to initiate (in Start())it like

Path[0]=new Path(); //etc
Then you can use it inside your CameraMove class as

Path[0].movePoints[currentPoint];'

Comment: But really what do you want to achieve? What is your intent? What you will do with that path? May be you better to use navMesh and automatic navigation, then implement own?

Comment: Ok, From the start. I wanted to know how I could adjust time/speed between specific waypoints with iTween. I asked it on the Unity forum: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/itween-adjusting-time-speed-between-specific-waypoints.454008/#post-3000508, but I got impatient and asked my problem here. So I had a question and from that question I got another question (getcomponent thing..). Maybe if you read it you'll understand it better.

Comment: Why I can't make it MonoBehaviour? Because if it's not a MonoBehaviour, it looks like this in the inspector: https://i.gyazo.com/6750be4b8aa6f2b22209d97e29f34a4d.png, which I want. If I do make it a MonoBehaviour, it looks like this in the inspector: https://i.gyazo.com/b424e19d31099d8af72e464931d510aa.png

Comment: They told me that it was better to make multiple paths to solve the issue that I had, so I tried to do that.

Comment: got any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The primary objective of `GetComponent` is to get a *component* attached to the game object. This means that `GetComponent` can only get objects of classes **deriving from** `UnityEngine.Component`. Note that `MonoBehaviour` is a subclass of `Component`, so any and all `MonoBehaviour` subclasses are subclasses of `Component`. Also note that *only components, i.e. classes deriving `Component`* show up in the inspector of a game object.

The class `Paths` does **not** inherit the class `Component`, either directly or indirectly. Thus it *can't* be **added** to an object or *retrieved* from an object using `GetComponent`.

As you specify in the comments, an object of type `CameraMove.Paths` is in another component of type `CameraMove`. If the other `CameraMove` component is on *another* game object, things become incredibly easy. You won't even need `GetComponent` for this. Just create a field `public CameraMove otherCameraMove` (I prefer a `private` field with the `SerializeField` attribute, but it doesn't matter here since you're obviously new to Unity) and select the other `CameraMove` object in the inspector. You'll be able to access the paths variable as `otherCameraMove.Path`.

If the other `CameraMove` component is on the *same* object however, things get more tricky. I, for one, suggest that game objects should **never, ever** have more than one instance of the same component. But if you do, you'll have to use `GetComponents<CameraMove>()` to retrieve *all* components of type `CameraMove` on the game object and iterate through the array looking for the `CameraMove` component which you want. This is just one of the reasons why in my opinion same components shouldn't be added to the same object more than once.

Comment: Thank you for the explaining. I did this and like you said, I am able to acces otherCameraMove.Path. But that variable is in the CameraMove class and I need the movePoints variable from the Paths class.